# How to generate and download .imp file in asp.net and what MIME type should I use?

Tags: asp.net, download, file-handling

```html
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace QCSL
{
    public partial class ImpDownload : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Getting the Id
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
            // Generating the file
            string fname = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".IMP";
            string TgFile = Server.MapPath("~/downloads/") + fname;
            BinaryWriter fs = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(TgFile, FileMode.Create));
            string header = "<Version>'12001','1'</Version>\n";
            string Body = "";
            string BodyH = "<Salinvoice>\n";
            string BodyF = "</Salinvoice>\n";
            //Generating the Content body
            string custid="*";
            string invnum="*";
            string invdate="*";
            string invamount="*";
            string tax="*";
            string BodyC = "'"+custid+ "',',',',',',',',','\n'1', ,'" + invnum + "','" + invdate + "','0', ,'.00','0','1','0','1','5','.00'\n'90000','1.0000','" + invamount + "','" + invamount + "','1','0','1','5','" + tax + "'\n";
            Body = BodyH + BodyC + BodyF;
            fs.Write(header + Body);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
            fs.Close();
            // downloading the file
            Response.ContentType = "application/imp";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fname);
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/downloads/" + fname));
            Response.End();
            //this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the following code to generate and download .imp file.I do not now what ContentType should I use however code is working fine. Any help will be appreciated very greatly.
**I have also added source file.**
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific type defined for IMP file, you can use `application/octet-stream` or `application/unknown` .

if your file is of type `Simply Accounting - Data Import` then use `application/vnd.accpac.simply.imp` . You can get all the list of mime type [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)